# TransactionScope + NHIbernate multiple sessions

Tags: c#, nhibernate, transactionscope

im writing database related tests, but they take long time to complete and im trying to speed them up..

my current code looks like this:

```
[TestClass]
public class TestClass
{
    private const string ConnectionString = "...";
    private const string TemplateDatabaseBackupPath = "...";

    [ClassInitialize]
    public static void ClassInitialize(TestContext context) {
        InitializeTestEnviroment(); // create & fill db, init internals

        using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(ConnectionString)) {
            connection.Open();
            using (SqlCommand command = connection.CreateCommand()) {
                command.CommandText = "BACKUP DATABASE [Testing] TO DISK = @path";
                command.Parameters.AddWithValue("path", TemplateDatabaseBackupPath);
                command.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }
        }
    }

    [TestCleanup]
    public static void TestCleanup() {
        using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(ConnectionString)) {
            connection.Open();

            using (SqlCommand command = connection.CreateCommand()) {
                command.CommandText = "ALTER DATABASE [Testing] SET SINGLE_USER WITH ROLLBACK IMMEDIATE";
                command.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }

            using (SqlCommand command = connection.CreateCommand()) {
                command.CommandText = @"RESTORE DATABASE [Testing] FROM DISK = @path WITH REPLACE";
                command.Parameters.AddWithValue("path", TemplateDatabaseBackupPath);
                command.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }
        }
    }

    [TestMethod]
    public void TestMethod() {
         Entity entity = new Entity { Name = "Fred Flindstone" };
         BlackBox.UpdateEntity(entity, 42);

         Entity actual = BlackBox.GetEntityById(42);
         Assert.AreEqual("Fred Flindstone", actual.Name);
    }

    [TestMethod]
    public void TestMethod2() {
         Entity entity = new Entity { Name = "Fred Flindstone" };
         BlackBox.UpdateEntity(entity, 42); // 42 = entity id

         Entity actual = BlackBox.GetEntityById(42);
         Assert.AreEqual("Fred Flindstone", actual.Name);
    }
}

// NH mapping class
public class Entity {
    public int Id;
    public string Name;
}

// Not real code - just to get the idea how CRUD are performed internally,  this code cannot be easily changed (no unit tests for it)
public static class BlackBox {
    public static void UpdateEntity(object entity, int id) {
        using(var s = GetSession()){
            s.Update(id, entity);
        }
    }

    public static void GetEntityById(int id) {
        using(var s = GetSession()){
            return s.Session.Query<Entity>().Single(o => o.Id == Id);
        }
    }

    private static IHiberSession GetSession(){ 
        return ...; // not relevant
    }

    public interface IHiberSession {
        ISession Session { get; }
        ...
    }
}
```

after some mesumenents i found this:

```
ClassInitialize                8s
TestMethod and TestMethod2     ~20ms
TestCleanup                    3s
```

obviously i would like to reduce TestCleanup time ...

after some searching i found System.Transactions.TransactionScope and thought i have a winner:

```
[ClassInitialize]
public static void ClassInitialize(TestContext context) {
    InitializeTestEnviroment();
}

[TestInitialize]
public static void TestInitialize() {
    _Scope = new System.Transactions.TransactionScope();
}

[TestCleanup]
public static void TestCleanup() {
    _Scope.Dispose(); // Rollback any changes made by test
}
```

with should be faster than database restore but unfortunately
i get this exception during in session Close() method

```
System.InvalidOperationException: Disconnect cannot be called while a transaction is in progress.
```

with seems to be related to this closed issue: [NH-1744](https://nhibernate.jira.com/browse/NH-1744) but that dont give me any idea, gow to fix my code :(

Anyway my question is how to make this code to work:

```
void TestMethod() {
    using(var scope = new System.Transactions.TransactionScope()) {

        // these two usings cannot be changed ...
        using (ISession session = GetSession()) {
             // some CRUD
        }

        using (ISession session = GetSession()) {
            // some more CRUD
        }
    }
}
```

or any other idea, how to make database fast backup/restore? (in-memory backup would be nice)

PS: TransactionScope is used ONLY in unit testing, 'live' code is scopeless

Thanks for any help ...